# jquery toggle multiple id

Tags: javascript, jquery

I found a sample program from w3school, and I manage to edit it. but the problem is, it is too consuming of codes, what I want is a short version of this code. Is it possible?
(I tried to put the div in php include,I use a single toggle function and multiple button but once I click a button all the div show).

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script>
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("#p1").hide();
    $("#p2").hide();
    $("#p3").hide();
    $("#p4").hide();

$("#button1").click(function(){
        $("#p1").toggle();
    });
$("#button2").click(function(){
        $("#p2").toggle();
    });
$("#button3").click(function(){
        $("#p3").toggle();
    });
$("#button4").click(function(){
        $("#p4").toggle();
    });
});
</script>
</head>
<body>

<div id="p1">

<p>This is a paragraph with little content.</p>
<p>This is another small paragraph.</p>

</div>
<button id="button1">Toggle</button>
<br>
<br>
<br>

<div id="p2">

<p>This is a paragraph with little content.</p>
<p>This is another small paragraph.</p>

</div>
<button id="button2">Toggle</button>
<br>
<br>
<br>

<div id="p3">

<p>This is a paragraph with little content.</p>
<p>This is another small paragraph.</p>

</div>
<button id="button3">Toggle</button>
<br>
<br>
<br>

<div id="p4">

<p>This is a paragraph with little content.</p>
<p>This is another small paragraph.</p>

</div>
<button id="button4">Toggle</button>
<br>
<br>
<br>

</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can re-organize the HTML first and with shorter script.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script>
      $(document).ready(function(){

        $(".msg").hide();

        $(".toggle").click(function(){
            $(this).parent( "div" ).find(".msg").toggle();
        });

      });
    </script>
  </head>
  <body>

    <div>
      <div class="msg">
        <p>This is a paragraph with little content.</p>
        <p>This is another small paragraph.</p>
      </div>
    <button class="toggle">Toggle</button>
    </div>
    <br><br><br>

    <div>
      <div class="msg">
        <p>This is a paragraph with little content.</p>
        <p>This is another small paragraph.</p>
      </div>
    <button class="toggle">Toggle</button>
    </div>
    <br><br><br>

    <div>
      <div class="msg">
        <p>This is a paragraph with little content.</p>
        <p>This is another small paragraph.</p>
      </div>
    <button class="toggle">Toggle</button>
    </div>
    <br><br><br>

    <div>
      <div class="msg">
        <p>This is a paragraph with little content.</p>
        <p>This is another small paragraph.</p>
      </div>
    <button class="toggle">Toggle</button>
    </div>
    <br><br><br>

  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: your code works perfect! but in my actual code didnt work.. the mistake is in my code..

Comment: I guess you haven't **<div>** to contain both the message and button **</div>** as a group. You can see  that from the button point of view, it gets the **parent div**, then in this div, it finds the **msg div**, so only the message of this group is selected instead of all messages.

Answer (score 2):

You can shorten your code like this just make sure you add the proper attributes to the html elements

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $(".toggleDiv").hide();
  

  $(".btnToggle").click(function() {
    var div = $(this).attr("data-div");
    $("#" + div).toggle();
  });


});
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.0/jquery.min.js"></script>

</head>

<body>

  <div id="p1" class="toggleDiv">

    <p>This is a paragraph with little content.</p>
    <p>This is another small paragraph.</p>

  </div>
  <button id="button1" class="btnToggle" data-div="p1">Toggle</button>
  <br>
  <br>
  <br>

  <div id="p2" class="toggleDiv">

    <p>This is a paragraph with little content.</p>
    <p>This is another small paragraph.</p>

  </div>
  <button id="button2" class="btnToggle" data-div="p2">Toggle</button>
  <br>
  <br>
  <br>

  <div id="p3" class="toggleDiv">

    <p>This is a paragraph with little content.</p>
    <p>This is another small paragraph.</p>

  </div>
  <button id="button3" class="btnToggle" data-div="p3">Toggle</button>
  <br>
  <br>
  <br>

  <div id="p4" class="toggleDiv">

    <p>This is a paragraph with little content.</p>
    <p>This is another small paragraph.</p>

  </div>
  <button id="button4" class="btnToggle" data-div="p4">Toggle</button>
  <br>
  <br>
  <br>

</body>

</html>
```

Comment: It work sir, but I want is just a single div called by those 4 button,

Comment: I try this one you gave me an idea

Comment: In the button's  data-div attribute. Put the id of the div you want to call :)